Pass id to @Html.ActionLink in view with nested model class in ASP.NET MVC
I want to create a call to controller action with just carrying id, that is received form model, instead of passing whole model to controller.
My model is:
public class SingleProduct
{
     [JsonProperty("product")]
     public Product1 Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product1
{
     [JsonProperty("id")]
     public double? Id { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("title")]
     public string? Title { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Body")]
     [JsonProperty("body_html")]
     public string? Body_html { get; set; }
}

This is my view:
@model SingleProduct
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Title)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Body_html)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Body_html)
        </div>

        <form asp-action="DeleteProduct">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product.Id)   
            <div class="form-group">
                // this is the part causing error
                @Html.ActionLink(
                         "Delete",
                         "DeleteProduct",
                         new { id = Product.Id })  

                <a href="Update_Delete/DeleteProduct?id=@Product.Id">Confirm Delete</a>
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

This is my controller action:
[HttpPost]
// Any way to receive Product.Id without model?
public IActionResult DeleteProduct(long id)  
{
    // rest of the code
}


ActionLink creates a link, which is a GET. You are showing a method that expects a POST. And you don't want to make it a GET.

Delete action can be achieved by HttpGet, since you are not updating anything, hence, no need for complex viewModel form submitting. Just replace your Html with only bewl i.e.
...

@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteProduct", new { id = Product.Id }) 

...

Change your action method to
...

[HttpGet]

...

This will resolve your issue.
